# SQL injection with multiple statements disabled?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-injection

I am testing SQL injection. I have a query:

`SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE testVar='<USER INPUT HERE>';`

I have disabled multiple statements in one line. Is there any way an attacker might slip an UPDATE or DELETE in there and kill my data?

NOTE: I am aware that parameterizing my queries is more secure and I already do so. However, I would like to know of all of the possibilities.

Comment: `I have disabled multiple statements in one line.` how?

Comment: Err, I kind of reverted back to an older version of MySQL.

Comment: everything for the security, huh? IT's not ok to go back 3 versions just because of security.. If you're using PHP, `mysql_query` already restricts number of queries to 1

Comment: If you're already using parameters in prepared statements, there's no way someone can inject anything into the SQL statement. Any other questions about injection possibilities are thus moot.

Comment: I read this and think of this cartoon... http://xkcd.com/327/  Got to love xkcd.  As others have said, use parameters and your code is safer from injection.

Answer (score 2):

even if you have disable multiple line statements, what if your user input looks like

```
a' OR 1=1; '
```

I guess this will select all the rows.

your query will become

```
SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE testVar='a' OR 1=1 ;'';
```

Answer (score -2):

They can if you do not properly escape quotes in your user input

Comment: how? I'm asking specifically about `UPDATE`/`DELETE`/commands that would actually alter my data.